# Monotonicity of Relative Entropy with Respect to Temperature

Tags: statistical-mechanics, quantum-information, entropy

Consider a bipartite quantum system $A\otimes B$ with arbitrary Hamiltonian $\hat{H}$. Consider the partial trace of the canonical ensemble as a function of temperature.
$$\rho_A(T)=Tr_B\left(\frac{e^{-\beta\hat{H}}}{Z}\right)$$
Consider the function $f$ defined using quantum relative entropy by
$$f(T)=S(\rho_A(0)\|\rho_A(T))$$

Is $f$ an nondecreasing function?

More generally, let's define this function.
$$g(T_1,T_2)=S(\rho_A(T_1)\|\rho_A(T_2))$$

Can we say that $\frac{\partial g}{\partial T_1}\geq0$ and $\frac{\partial g}{\partial T_2}\leq0$ if and only if $T_1\geq T_2$?

These relations make some intuitive sense since relative entropy is a measure of the 'distinguishability' or 'distance' between states. Furthermore, $g$ is minimized at zero if $T_1=T_2$. So, these relations must be true in a neighbourhood of $T_1=T_2$.

Is it possible to prove these inequalities mathematically?

Comment: Your title asks about monotonicity of the relative entropy with temperature, while the question is about reduced density matrices of thermal states. Is this on purpose?

Answer (score 1):

> Is $f$ an nondecreasing function?

No, $f$ need not be a non-decreasing function.

As a counterexample, consider e.g. two qubits with a Hamiltonian
$$
H = E_0 \lvert 01\rangle\langle01\rvert  + 
E_1 \lvert 11\rangle\langle11\rvert  \ .
$$

Then,
$$
\rho_A(T) \propto \big(1+e^{-E_0/T}\big)\,\lvert 0\rangle\langle 0 \vert + 
\big(1+e^{-E_1/T}\big)\,\lvert 1\rangle\langle 1 \vert\ .
$$

Setting, e.g., $E_0=1$, $E_1=2$ (if fact, any non-zero $E_0\ne E_1$ will do), it is now easy to check that the function $f$ has a maximum at some finite $T$, after which it decreases again to zero (indeed, it *must* do so as $\rho_A(0)=\rho_A(\infty)$).